# Indexing a batch of images (3D numpy array) using a 2D array to get pixel values for each image

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a 3D array representing a batch of images (batch_size x W x H)

`images = np.random.rand(8,100,100)`

and a 2D array (batch_size x 2)

`indices = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(8, 2))`

which contains x,y indices for accessing pixel values of the images. The following

`images[:,indices[:,0],indices[:,1]`

returns an array of shape (8,8) but I would like to get an array of shape (8,) that contains pixel values for each image at the respective x, y positions stored in `indices`.

Looking for a way to index the array w/o using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved it. Just needed to get the diagonal of the output:

`output = images[:,indices[:,0],indices[:,1]`

`np.diag(output)` gives pixel values for each image at x,y positions (indices).